# Binding an Image Source based on property change of another object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, xamarin.forms

I have an object which have for which I can bind a property like this:

```
<Label Text = "{Binding id}"/>
```

The binding there is done correctly. Now I would like to bind an image based on the property of the label.
I tried to use the DataTrigger like this

```
<Image >
  <Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
      <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding id}" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Source"   Value="mypic.png"/>
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
   </Image.Style>
 </Image>
```

But I am having the following error: The given key was not present in the dictionary. Everything look OK. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to be related to the XAML you're showing. Provided that there is an image file or resource with that name, the XAML should work.

Comment: You could use converter as well and give image path in converter,

Comment: @Firoz For what reason? An Image Style like this should just work.

Comment: I do have an Image. Or should I include the whole path to the resource (image) ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
TargetType="Image"
```

to the **DataTrigger** tag. Your code should be like this:

```
<Image >
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding id}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Source"   Value="mypic.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```